# Are there any free databases of audio-visual emotional stimuli (English)?

Tags: perception, emotion

I am particularly interested in naturalistic and induced emotional content. I have found the SAVEE, the HUMAINE and the SEMAINE databases. I have read through the Terms for LDC (UPenn) and it seems somewhat complicated, especially as I am interested in their databases from 1993 and 2002. I have also found the EULA/ELDA resources, but these do not have much to offer. I have seen a passing reference to Glenn I. Roisman's database of Adult Attachment Interview recordings which seems to be perfect but I cannot get through to anyone from that team to inquire about availability.

**Do you know any other databases of naturalistic/induced emotional stimuli which would be audio-visual and in English?**

Comment: [duplicate?](http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/q/1864/55) or are you specifically looking for stimuli that are audio AND visual, rather than audio OR visual?

Comment: Even we are working on identification of emotions. We need audio, video and physiological signals for our research. Could you please help by sharing the data that is available with you

Answer (score 3):

We have been using audio databases from THE CENTER FOR THE STUDY OF EMOTION AND ATTENTION. 
Video databases we received from Anna Esposito & Maria Teresa Riviello:
http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1694104
http://dl.acm.org/author_page.cfm?id=81100065756&CFID=220607811&CFTOKEN=47568792